# How to share a json-document to another json-documents in mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid, jsonschema

I've json-documents and ruby classes

`product` json-document:

```js
{
  "taxon_id": "5281bbed3aa823f9439dc02d",
  "name": "Mongoid in Action",
  "seo":
  {
    "permalink": "mongoid-in-action",
    "metadata":
    {
      "description": "Great programming book by smarter authors",
      "keywords": ["mongoid", "book", "action"],
      "title": "Programming book: Mongoid in Action"
    }
  }
}
```

`taxon` json-document:

```js
{
  "_id": "5281bbed3aa823f9439dc02d",
  "name": "Programming",
  "seo":
  {
    "permalink": "programming",
    "metadata":
    {
      "description": "Catalogue for programming books",
      "keywords": ["programming", "coding", "hacking"],
      "title": "Programming books"
    }
  }
}
```

`documents/matadata.rb` file:

```rb
class Documents::Metadata
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :description, type: String
  field :title,       type: String
  field :keywords,    type: Array,  default: []

  embedded_in :seo
end
```

`documents/seo.rb` file:

```rb
class Documents::Seo
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :permalink, type: String

  embeds_one :metadata
  embedded_in :product
  embedded_in :taxon

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :metadata
end
```

`documents/product.rb` file:

```rb
class Documents::Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_one :seo
  belongs_to :taxon

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo
end
```

`documents/taxon.rb` file:

```rb
class Documents::Taxon
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :name, type: String

  embeds_one :seo
  has_many :products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :seo
end
```

I've common seo json-document and want to share between another documents.
Is it right division or not? Are json-schemas suitable?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking correct just correct one change in all the models, for lines like embeds_one and embedded_in mention the class name because rails resolve the relations by model name Like if you put `embeds_one :seo` it will look for class name SEO not Documents::Seo. Put it like this

```
 embeds_one :seo, :class_name => "Documents::Seo"
```